# How to run docker-compose with GUI

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I was using the command `sudo docker build -t d-image .` to compile a dockerfile and then the command

`sudo docker run -e DISPLAY -v $HOME/.Xauthority:/home/mycompter/.Xauthority -v /dev/shm:/dev/shm --net=host d-image`

to run the image `d-image` with a GUI since it has a python script that calls google chrome and it works really well.

The problem is that I'm now using docker-compose with `sudo docker-compose up` for the following docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3"
services:
  docker-image:
    build: .
    deploy:
      replicas: 5
      update_config:
        parallelism: 1
        delay: 10s
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure
```

which runs the image but without the GUI and I don't know where and when to run the command `sudo docker run -e DISPLAY -v $HOME/.Xauthority:/home/mycompter/.Xauthority -v /dev/shm:/dev/shm --net=host d-image` or something similar to get the GUI with docker-compose

Answer (score 1):

You can change your docker-compose file like below:

```sh
version: "3"
services:
  docker-image:
    build: .
    deploy:
      replicas: 5
      update_config:
        parallelism: 1
        delay: 10s
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure
    volumes:
      - ~/.Xauthority:/home/mycompter/.Xauthority
      - /dev/shm:/dev/shm
    environment:
      - DISPLAY: <PUT_YOUR_DISPLAY_VALUE_HERE>
    network_mode: "host"
```

You have to replace `<PUT_YOUR_DISPLAY_VALUE_HERE>` with whatever the value you have in your environment for `DISPLAY`.

You can get that value by calling:

```sh
echo $DISPLAY
```

Comment: my mistake, it builds and runs and no longer shows the error but is not showing GUI

Comment: No problem, what is your `DISPLAY` value?

Comment: the display value is 10

Comment: There is no error on the console as well?

Comment: `WARNING: Some services (docker-image) use the "deploy" key, which will be ignored. Compose does not support "deploy" configuration - use "docker stack deploy" to deploy to a swarm.
Starting contenedor_docker-image ... done
Attaching to contenedor_docker-image`

Comment: `docker-image  | Failed to move to new namespace: PID namespaces supported, Network namespace supported, but failed: errno = Operation not permitted`

Comment: Well, I'm afraid without knowing much about your use case here, I might not be able to help you anymore regarding this. I hope someone else will help you here. Sorry!